# Delphi Getting 'Ctrl Tab' and 'Ctrl Shift Tab' in application

Tags: delphi, user-interface, navigation, tabs, components

In my application I use tabs, my own component, like Google chrome sort of. Each tab reference an explorer component so it is basicly a tabbed browser/explorer. My problem is that I want to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +<kbd>TAB</kbd> to navigate tabs. Setting forms.KeyPreview will not help since the tab key is special key. How can I, in an easy way, add support for my navigation wish. I can modify component if needed. My component is based on TCustomControl if that helps.

Kind Regards
Roy M Klever

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tab, like the arrow keys, enter and escape are a special keys used in dialog navigation. When a control would like to receive those keys it has to indicate so by responding to [WM_GETDLGCODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645425%28VS.85%29.aspx). Like this code below. Then you will receive a KeyDown event when Tab is pressed.

```
procedure WMGetDlgCode(var Msg: TWMGetDlgCode); message WM_GETDLGCODE;

procedure TYourControl.WMGetDlgCode(var Msg: TWMGetDlgCode);
begin
 inherited;
 Msg.Result := Msg.Result or DLGC_WANTTAB;
end;
```

Also see [here](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=591) and [here](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_670.asp?SK=).

PS: And make sure your control has focus or you will receive nothing at all (if CanFocus then SetFocus; in MouseDown).

Comment: Well this helped me getting on right track... I had some code in my explorer that stopped the keys from working under some conditions. Now I have it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can manage the CM_DIALOGKEY message in your component to intercept the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

```
procedure CMDialogKey(var Message: TCMDialogKey); message CM_DIALOGKEY;
```

check this sample

```
procedure TYourComponent.CMDialogKey(var Message: TCMDialogKey);
begin
  if (Focused) and (Message.CharCode = VK_TAB) and (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0) then
  begin
   if GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) then
    GoBackwardPage()//you must write this method
   else
    GoForwardPage()//you must write this method
    Message.Result := 1;
  end
   else
    inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Almost how I do it now :) Thanks!